# Using jQuery to Retrieve Text from an HTML Element

Tags: jquery

So i have a set of links that all must call the same ajax function through jQuery.  To simplify this, I have used

```
$('#nav').click(function() {...});
```

where each has the same `<a id="nav"...>`I want to retrieve only the text of the HTML element clicked on, but using the `.text()` function in ajax retrieves the text of each `$('#nav')` element.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS id's are only to be used once. Change your #nav to a class and you're good:

```
<a class="nav">
```

and get the text like this

```
$('.nav').click(function() { alert($(this).text()); });
```